# any reference for KQL query library for angular project

Tags: angular, kql

I'm looking for third party library that works for KQL query preparation in angular project so that we can validate in client side.

Note: I have found someway in C# side but here I'm looking for client side

any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1):

The following library includes transpiled code from C# to javascript.
It is not well documented (well, not documented at all actually), but it knows how to parse KQL queries if that's what y
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kusto/language-service-next